# cordova typescript Media plugin MediaPlayer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

In Visual Studio Community 2017, I started with the "Ionic 2 - Sidemenu" template. (Ionic2, Angular2, TypeScript) I want to use the Media cordova plugin, and play an (audio) mp3 file.  Case: the app opens > the audio controls are displayed > the actor taps the play button > the audio file plays.

In VS, I used the config.xml > Plugins UI to install the plugin. Then in my app.component.ts file I have this at the top.

```
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';
```

And this in the same file

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    console.log(MediaPlugin);
  });
}
```

Which spits out this in the console.
[image]

Question #1: do I have to do

```
var myPlayer = new Media(src, success, fail)
```

somewhere in a ts file?  I'm thinking I have to use different code because I am using TypeScript.

Question #2: What do I put in the html to display the media player in the UI?  I have this in the html now

```
<audio controls></audio>
```

But maybe I need something else because I am using ionic.

Currently I try to make the player play an mp3 file with this for a buttons click handler:

```
setSrc() {
    var myPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    // the intellisense verifies that this path is correct
    myPlayer.src = '../../audio/Capitolo_7s.mp3'; 
}
```

I get an error in the Media player's UI:

```
This type of audio file isn't supported
```

Thanks.

Comment: how are you accessing your mp3 files  using url ? or will the file will be inside the app?

Comment: The mp3 file will be on the local device.  Strictly speaking, not really inside the app.

Comment: I need to know how to get the Media player working in this app, so that the controls display and the player is able to play, pause, and seek with a local mp3 file.

Comment: To start with: which version of ionic-native are you using? And further: Why do you start a new project with an old version of ionic?

Comment: @pdschuller what do you mean by not really inside the app means?

Comment: @Webruster the mp3 files will be in the device's file system.  Like maybe in the Downloads directory.

Comment: @pdschuller my question is are you exporting the audio files along with the html ?

Comment: No.  The mp3 files are not part of the app.

Comment: @pdschuller thanks for expanding your question , from the error i can state that your app at run time unable to resolve the path , try to verify with the static path where mp3 file in the application , if its worked then you can confirm that the problem is in path resolution

Answer (score 1):

Ionic have a wrapper for the cordova native plugin

check their documentation and usage in this link
[Ionic Native - Media](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/)